# Magento 2 - WorldPay for Business checkout error

Tags: magento2, checkout, currency, worldpay

I have an issue while trying to checkout using the WorldPay payment method. WorldPay checkout working fine with Pound and Euro currency only, not with other currencies like USD, PKR etc.

When I change the currency to Pound or Euro from currency switcher from frontend and checkout, WorldPay works fine but not other currencies.

[image]

Any configuration and M2 setting issue?  Need help

Comment: Please specify which module you have suing

Comment: I am using Meetanshi WorldPay for Business Module.